# Can't change help_post text in Price Set using the civicrm_buildAmount hook

Tags: hooks, price-sets

There are several fields I expect to be able to change in the buildAmount hook that just won't change for me. One example:

```
function myext_civicrm_buildAmount($pageType, &$form, &$amount) {

      $feeBlock =& $amount;

      foreach ( $feeBlock as &$fee ) {

          if ( !is_array( $fee['options'] ) ) {
            continue;
          }

      // My debug-to-file function prints the original value as expected
      // fdebug($fee['help_post']);

      $fee['help_post'] = 'New help text';

      // My debug-to-file function prints the new value as expected
      // fdebug($fee['help_post']);

      // But the value in the price set, when rendered, does not change

      }
}
```

The help_post text remains as originally set in the price set. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Just as a thought i think you may need to set $amount = $feeBlock right at the end as your modifying $amount

Comment: Good thought. But, I tried that and still no luck. I even skipped the $feeBlock variable and referenced $amount directly and my help_post values are still not changing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do:

```
foreach ($feeBlock as $feeBlockId => $fee) {
   .....
   $feeBlock[$feeBlockId]['help_post'] = "blahblah"
}
```